# Unable to update WorkItem Status with WorkItemTrackingHttpClient

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I am automating updates to work item hours but changes to Status are ignored. I'd like to set status from "Active" to "Resolved".

I have found information stating that you also need to set a "Reason" if you are changing the status but my code isn't changing Reason or Status although all the other field updates are working. I suspect it is because the Status field is read-only but we are unable to find a rule that makes it so (we're using the CMMI template):

[image]

Can someone tell me if the problem is the setup in dev ops or if it is my code (or something else)?

```
//Executing from LINQPad, no need to mention the blocks on async....

WorkItem targetWorkItem = client.GetWorkItemAsync(123456).Result;    

JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

patchDocument.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Replace,
        Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork",
        Value = 123
    }
);

patchDocument.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Replace,
        Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork",
        Value = 0
    }
);

/*
    These don't work! I think because "Reason" field is read only
*/
patchDocument.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add, //Tried Replace as well as Add
        Path = "/Fields/System.Reason",
        Value = "Complete and Requires Review/Test"
    }

patchDocument.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Operation = Operation.Add, //Tried Replace as well as Add
        Path = "/Fields/System.State",
        Value = "Resolved"
    }
);

//Succeeds for any field except Status and Reason
WorkItem result = client.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, 123456).Result;
```

Namespaces used:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi  
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json
```

Comment: Upvoted for the UpdateWorkItemAsync() sample code ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you should write `/fields/System.State` with `f` and not `Fields` with `F`.

And change the state is enough, the reason will be changed automatically.

Comment: Astonishing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json should end up looking like this:

```
{
     "id": xx,
     "rev": yy,
     "fields": [{
         "field": {
             "refName": "System.State"
         },

         "value": "Resolved"
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "System.Reason"
         },

         "value": "Status Reason"
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy"
         },

         "value": null
     },

     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate"
         },

         "value": null
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate"
         },

         "value": "2014-08-25T19:14:04.594Z"
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy"
         },

         "value": "User Name"
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason"
         },

         "value": "Resolved Reason"
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate"
         },

         "value": <null or "2014-08-25T19:14:04.594Z">
     },
     {
         "field": {
             "refName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy"
         },
         "value": <null, "John Doe">
     }]
 }
```